# How to handle subview's gesture events in superview's controller?

Tags: ios, swift

I am a web developer and new to iOS programming.

I have two files. `ViewController.swift` and `FilterList.swift`. When I hit `Commend + R`, the simulator came out and the style seemed right. But clicking `FilterList`'s instance view didn't print anything.

How can I get this working? I just want to have one UI component and its events in a single view. Something like in current Front-End Development such as React and Vue. Or are there some preferred ways to handle this?

`ViewController.swift`:

```swift
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {


  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    let kindsList = FilterList()

    view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    view.backgroundColor = .blue
    kindsList.handleTapGesture = {(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer ) -> Void in
      print("In UIViewController")
    }
    view.addSubview(kindsList)
  }
}
```

`FilterList.swift`:

```swift
import UIKit

class FilterList: UIView {

  private let titleBarStackView = UIStackView()
  private let titleBarImage = UIImage(systemName: "chevron.right", withConfiguration: UIImage.SymbolConfiguration(pointSize: 16, weight: .regular, scale: .medium))
  private let titleBarImageView = UIImageView()
  private let titleBarLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 160, height: 28))

  // MARK:- Styles
  private let spacing: CGFloat = 16.0

  var labelText = "title"
  var handleTapGesture: ((UITapGestureRecognizer) -> Void)?

  convenience init(label: String) {

    self.init()
    self.labelText = label
    // Tap Gesture
    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handleTap))

    titleBarStackView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    titleBarStackView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    self.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

  }

  override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.


    // Configure Arrow
    titleBarImageView.image = titleBarImage

    // Configure Label
    titleBarLabel.text = labelText
    titleBarLabel.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .headline)

    titleBarStackView.addArrangedSubview(titleBarLabel)
    titleBarStackView.addArrangedSubview(titleBarImageView)
    self.addSubview(titleBarStackView)
    setupConstraints()


  }

  private func setupConstraints() {
    titleBarStackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
      titleBarStackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.superview!.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: spacing),
      titleBarStackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.superview!.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -spacing),
      titleBarStackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.superview!.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: spacing),
    ])
  }

  @objc func handleTap(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    print("IN UIView")
    self.handleTapGesture?(sender)
  }
}
```

Comment: You are initializing your `FilterList` without parameters but adding the `GestureRecognizer` in the convenience initializer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the initializer that setup the tap gesture for stackView i.e, `FilterList(label:`. And provide size for the `FilterList` so that it has the touchable area. Update as below,

```
let kindsList = FilterList(label: "Stack")
kindsList.handleTapGesture = {(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer ) -> Void in
    print("In UIViewController")
}
kindsList.frame = self.view.bounds // Update this to your requirement
view.addSubview(kindsList)
```

Comment: Adding `kindsList.frame = self.view.bounds` works. I think that's the key. The initializer didn't get called is a slip. I somehow omitted the `label` argument in this version of code.